# Can we manipulate the speed at which the WRITE/WRITELINE functions write into the file?

Tags: python

I wish to change the speed at which the Write() or writeline() functions write into a file with. Is it possible to vary the rate? If not, do you know any external modules which can help?

For example:
I have to write a 500 word essay into the .txt or .rtx file. I want the rate of typing using write to be say, 100 words a minute.
so after 5mins, the file is written completely.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `time.sleep()` between calls to `write()` or `writeline()` to slow down the rate as desired.